# Unit testing a chain of network requests - how many tests?

Tags: unit-testing, programming-practices

I have some fairly complex code, that is a chain of API calls. The result of one call is the input of the next.

```swift
class PaymentService {
   func pay(userId: String) async {
      let paymentSource = await thirdPartyService.createPaymentSource() // A
      let order = await orderService.createOrder(paymentSource: paymentSource) // B
      let result = await paymentService.chargeUser(userId: userId, order: order) // C
   }
```

I would like to test that:

- The methods are called
- The correct parameters are passed into each step

**How many tests would you write for something like this?**

- On one hand, most TDD material suggests that tests should test a single thing, and if the test fails, there should be a single reason why this happened.
- On the other hand, I feel like there is a lot of duplicated setup code, and a single test might be easier to understand.

### Multiple tests:

```swift
// Tests line A
func test_pay_callsThirdPartyService() {
    // Given
    mockThirdPartyService.createPaymentSource_returnValue = mockPaymentSource
    
    // When
    sut.buy(userId: "123")

    // Then
    assert(mockThirdPartyService.createPaymentSource_called) == true
}

// Tests line B
func test_pay_callsCreateOrder_withPaymentSource() {
    // Given
    let paymentSource = mockPaymentSource
    mockThirdPartyService.createPaymentSource_returnValue = paymentSource
    mockOrderService.createOrder_returnValue = mockOrder
    
    // When
    sut.buy(userId: "123")

    // Then
    assert(mockOrderService.createOrder_called) == true
    assert(mockOrderService.createOrder_paymentSource) == paymentSource
}

// Tests line C
func test_pay_callsChargeUser_withCreatedOrder() {
    // Given
    let order = mockOrder
    let userId = "123"

    mockThirdPartyService.createPaymentSource_returnValue = paymentSource
    mockOrderService.createOrder_returnValue = order
    mockPaymentService.chargeUser_returnValue = mockResult
    
    // When
    sut.buy(userId: userId)

    // Then
    assert(mockOrderService.chargeUser_called) == true
    assert(mockOrderService.createOrder_userId) == userId
    assert(mockOrderService.createOrder_order) == order
}
```

### Single test

```
func test_pay_callsPaymentChainCorrectly() {
    // Given
    let paymentSource = mockPaymentSource
    let order = mockOrder
    let userId = "123"

    mockThirdPartyService.createPaymentSource_returnValue = paymentSource
    mockOrderService.createOrder_returnValue = order
    mockPaymentService.chargeUser_returnValue = mockResult
    
    // When
    sut.buy(userId: userId)

    // Then
    // Tests line A
    assert(mockThirdPartyService.createPaymentSource_called) == true

    // Tests line B
    assert(mockOrderService.createOrder_called) == true
    assert(mockOrderService.createOrder_paymentSource) == paymentSource

    // Tests line C
    assert(mockOrderService.chargeUser_called) == true
    assert(mockOrderService.createOrder_userId) == userId
    assert(mockOrderService.createOrder_order) == order
}
```

Comment: Enough tests to provide a reasonable confidence level that the code works as it should.  For what it's worth, your second example is not TDD.

Comment: "How many tests would you write for something like this?" None - I'd sit down with a second developer, do a review, and then document that the code had been reviewed.  "So simple there are obviously no deficiencies" is a thing, and I don't see that the ceremony of creating a "unit test" for this code is going to lead to more customer value in either the short or long term.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Unfortunately, the code is not a simple as shown here, this was just an oversimplification of the problem for the sake of asking the question. In reality, there are 4+ payment methods, each with a slightly different chain of 3-4 network network calls. And it's completely untested. Though the essence of the question still remains the same, would you have 1 test for each link in the chain, or 1 test for the whole chain.

Answer (score 1):

You should write multiple tests.  Each service should have its own unit tests, which the other services mocked.  Ideally you would just have one assert per test.